# How to show bash set -x commands in colors?

Tags: bash, zsh, colors, debugging

I have a bash script which throws 100s of lines.
I can see which command doing this using `set -x` but it's difficult to find it on terminal.
If `set -x` option shows in color I can find it faster.

Is this possible in `bash` or `zsh`?

I tried trap but it's not working for file redirections

```
trap 'tput setaf 1;tput bold;echo $BASH_COMMAND;read;tput init' DEBUG
```

Comment: Is the script a `bash` script or a `zsh` script? Is the issue that you want to make the tracing output stand out more so that you can spot it in a log file? The tracing output should already be prefixed by the value of `$PS4` in both shells.

Comment: You can do this by piping `set -x` through a script which adds the escape-sequences.  A suitable answer (some will simply copy/paste and overlook this point...) will show how to handle multi-line values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `zsh`, you could define `$PS4` to something like:

```
PS4='%F{blue}%B+%N:%i>%b%f '
```

To have the xtrace prompt in bold and blue for instance (`+%N:%i>`  being the default value of `$PS4`, `%F{blue}` changes the foreground colour to blue and `%B` enables *bold* mode, `%f`/`%b` turning both off respectively).